# formula to find specific cell with data within range of cells

Tags: excel

I have a row of cells that I created an if scenario in that will give either a blank cell response or a address that is required if the column next to it lists a specific person in this survey workbook...only 1 cell will have data and it will be for that individual chosen, and all others will be blank at all times as each survey workbook is unique...now, I have another cell that I need for it to copy the address that will be listed at the time for this worksheet.....what formula would I use to retrieve that address listed from the cells?

Answer (score 0):

If all the cells are empty in a certain range apart from one, if you concatenate all the cell values in that range, you will have the answer.

For example, if you had the following cells:

```
[      ]
[      ]
[      ]
[ABC   ]
[      ]
```

If you concatenate all these cells, you would end up with:

```
[ABC   ]
```

Comment: THAT IS IT!!!!!! I use that formula all the time, but not in this fashion so didn't even think about it....it worked! Thank you SO MUCH!!